# Help with pointers in C using qsort, bsearch

Tags: c, pointers, qsort, bsearch

I'm having trouble with some of the pointer/array notation used.  I have two lists and am sorting them, and then try to display them.  I had 3 comments in my code below as to what the declarations are and why.  My code looks like:

```
int Compare(const void *a, const void *b);

void SortStudents(char *studentList[], size_t studentCount) 
{
    qsort(studentList, studentCount, sizeof(studentList[0]), Compare);
}

int Compare(const void *a, const void *b) 
{
    return (strcmp(*(char **)a, *(char **)b));
}

/*Determines which registrants did not attend the first meeting by searching for registrants 
 that are not in attendees set. */
void DisplayClassStatus(
                        const char *registrants[], size_t registrantCount,
                        const char *attendees[],   size_t attendeeCount)
{
    char **missedFirstMeeting; // not sure if this is the right declaration
    char *start, *end;

    // not sure if this is right with the &attendees and registrants for the bsearch()
    missedFirstMeeting = bsearch(&attendees, registrants, attendeeCount, 
                                 sizeof(attendees[0]), Compare);
    printf("Missed First Meeting: \n");

   //not sure if this the way to traverse through the array using pointers to display
    for (start = missedFirstMeeting, end = &missedFirstMeeting[registrantCount-1]; start < end; ++start) {
        printf("%s", *start);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be homework, so I'll answer in such a way as to (hopefully) lead you in the correct direction.

The `bsearch()` function searches for *one* element in a sorted list, and returns either its location, or an indicator saying it wasn't found. Your code as posted above appears to be using `bsearch()` in a different way.

Consider treating each registrant individually, and using `bsearch()` more than once to see whether each registrant is in the attendees list. If not, then show the registrant name. Don't forget that `bsearch()` only works correctly if the list is sorted.